# celery .env variables not used in settings.py

Tags: python, django, celery

I am stuck on using config vars from my .env file inside the settings.py for my celery.py.

when i hardcode `CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost'`, everything works, however, when i use `CELERY_BROKER_URL= os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')`, the REDIS_URL is not taken over and I get an error.

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'xlink.settings'

app = Celery('xlink')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

.env:

```
REDIS_URL = 'redis://localhost'
REDIS_PASSWORD = 'yow'
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
```

NOT WORKING settings.py version 1:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL= os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND= os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')
```

error version 1 (trying to take over the default redis set-up as noting is given):

```
[2017-08-26 10:57:09,253: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

NOT WORKING settings.py version 2:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://:{}@{}:6379/0'.format(
    os.environ.get('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
    os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST'))
```

error version 2 (clearly not taking over .env variables):

```
[2017-08-26 11:11:03,419: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://:**@none:6379/0: Error 8 connecting to none:6379. nodename nor servname provided, or not known..
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

WORKING settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL= 'redis://localhost'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND= 'redis://localhost'
```

tasks.py:

```
import celery
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: So how are you starting celery? What are you doing to tell it to pick up the env settings?

Comment: i run it on heroku or local. Heroku starts it from the procfile `worker: celery worker --app=tasks.app`. locally, I start it with following command: `celery -A xlink worker -l info`

Comment: btw, i also tried this inside celery.py: `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', xlink.settings')` and somehow tried to add this too to the strat-up command, but with no success

Comment: So as I said, you're not doing anything to actually load the env file locally. You need to start your worker via Foreman or `heroku local`.

Comment: i will check that out and post the answer or come back with more questions

Answer (score 2):

The big mistake I made was concerning running the celery worker separate from the commandline with this code:

```
celery -A xlink worker -l info
```

adding this line of code to the procfile and running with the heroku command solved this issue.

profile:

```
web: gunicorn xlink.wsgi --threads 4 --log-level debug
worker: celery -A xlink worker -l info
```

command to get it running:

```
heroku local worker
```

If you want to run both the worker and the web app in one terminal window, just do `heroku local` and both start simultaneously in one terminal window.

thanks for the hints @Daniel Roseman