# Using environment variables from .env in Django Celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, dotenv, django-anymail

I'm using **Django 2.x** and **Celery 4.3.x**

In my **Django** application, I'm using [dotenv](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv) to serve environment variable from `.env` file and to load the environment variable, I have following script in the `manage.py` and `wsgy.py` files

```
env_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '.env')
dotenv.read_dotenv(env_file)
```

The environment variables have AWS credentials being used by `anymail` plugin to send mail using **SES**.

Now, I'm using a Celery task to send the email and running the celery worker from the command line using

```
celery -A myapp worker -l debug
```

The worker is running but when sending an email, it gives an error in the celery task as

```
ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling 
the SendRawEmail operation: User `arn:aws:iam::user_id:user/my-laptop` is not 
authorized to permorm this action...
```

It seems trying to connect with my laptop's user instead of using the credentials defined in the `.env` file.

**How can I use the `.env` file to server the environment files to the Celery worker?**

Comment: Take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45894658/647002)—particularly the comments from Daniel Roseman. It sounds like the way you're starting Celery on the command line doesn't run any of your manage.py or wsgy.py code that would read dotenv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by loading the environment variable in the celery config file

`celery.py`

```
env_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))), '.env')
dotenv.read_dotenv(env_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it with dotenv but I use [python-decouple](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple) to pull parameters from a `.env` file in a few celery tasks.

```
from decouple import config

AUTH_USER = config('AUTH_USER')
AUTH_PASS = config('AUTH_PASS')
```